Influence class alignment to pack variables tightly
Suppose such structs: A is out of our control but we can change the B structure:
struct A {
  int64_t x;  // 8 bytes
  int32_t y;  // 4 bytes
              // 4 padding bytes
};

struct B {
  A a;        // 16 bytes
  int32_t z;  // 4 bytes
              // 4 padding bytes (alignof(B) == alignof(A) == 8)
};

static_assert(sizeof(B) == 24);  // 8 useless bytes!

Is there a way to put z inside A padding (some attributes)?

I understand the common idea for such behaviour, but what if want to force a different one?

Some compilers have a pack pragma, but be very careful using it. The struct may no longer be usable on systems with strict alignment requirements and will likely be slower on those that do not.

You could make A a class template to let it store any amount of extra information in a tuple for example.

@TedLyngmo we know nothing about A - only that it may have padding bytes

@AlexanderS Ok, then I would let it have those padding bytes. It's interesting that you know that it has them though. Is the compiler warning about it?

I do not receive any warnings, but wasting 8 bytes in this case makes me cry

Then, what does A do? Write your own A where you can pack all the information as tightly as it's possible.

It is more of an investigation (again :)). B stores A and some primitive type which is small, compered to A, and I would like to avoid extending B a lot (what if alignof(A) == 16?)

@AlexanderS Well, for the curiosity sake, user4581301 has the answer - most compilers have a __attribute__, #pragma or whatever other compiler-specific way to enforce no paddings. It obviously non-portable, since each compiler has its own syntax to write that, and as mentioned, it can possibly break aliasing requirements or at least make struct access slower.

Are you using the standard library classes? If you are, you may find 2 and 4 byte padding in those too. A class templates like std::vector may be full of internal padding and having quite a few vectors in an application isn't unusual.

@Yksisarvinen I agree, probably It's not worth it if we want to keep good performance

@TedLyngmo always) Wow, I thought STL containers are extremely well desined (no padding, etc.)

Take a look for yourself. Those I've looked at are well designed - and some have padding.

@AlexanderS I wouldn't consider "no padding" as a characteristic for being well-designed. If you have a system where few bytes of padding is an issue, you won't use standard containers anyway (bar std::array maybe). Standard containers are mostly designed for speed and usability. The one container designed for size is std::forward_list and I never saw anyone use it. Seriously, I think you focus on the wrong thing. Computers have gigabytes of RAM, embedded systems have megabytes. "Wasting" some of that for speed is always better unless you really find yourself in a constrained system.

They are well designed, but if the contents need padding, they need padding. And since that padding typically results in higher speed, well, lets just say trading RAM for speed is a time-honoured  programming tradition.

Reuse of padding is determined by the ABI, not the standard or the compiler. For example, on Linux this will work:
struct A {
  int64_t x;  // 8 bytes
  int32_t y;  // 4 bytes
              // 4 padding bytes
  A() = default;   // <-- CHANGE HERE
};

struct B {
  [[no_unique_address]] A a; // <-- CHANGE HERE
  int32_t z;  // 4 bytes in the padding of A
};

static_assert(sizeof(B) == 16);

godbolt
A needs certain properties true of its type in order to be eligible for tail padding reuse. For this ABI, it needs to be not a POD as of C++03. Adding a user-declared constructor is sufficient.
Then within B, we need to induce the use of tail padding. For example, if A is a base class, it will reuse its tail padding. Alternatively, using [[no_unique_address]] accomplishes the same.
